# Change setGame text every 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do something on the Discord Bot I want to change the setGame text every 10 minutes

For example, 10 minutes later, "#StayHome" => client.user.setGame(`#StayHome`);
or again after 10 minutes "!watch" = > client.user.setGame(`!watch`);

I want it to change the setGame text I want every 10 minutes. how can I do that ?

```
client.user.setStatus("online");
client.user.setGame(`!help`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **setInterval()** function and repeat it each 600000 ms (10 minutes).

```
let currentActivity = 0
let maxActivity = 3
setInterval(async () => {
    currentActivity++;
    if (currentActivity > maxActivity) {currentActivity = 0};
    switch(currentActivity) {
        case 0:
            client.user.setStatus("online");
            client.user.setGame(`!command`);
            break
        case 1:
            client.user.setStatus("online");
            client.user.setGame(`!hello`);
            break
        case 2:
            client.user.setStatus("online");
            client.user.setGame(`something`);
            break
        case 3:
            client.user.setStatus("online");
            client.user.setGame(`!help`);
            break
    };
}, 600000);
```

Using a switch statement you can change the status each 10 minutes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 5):

```
const bot = () => {
  let status = ["!help", "!watch", "#StayHome"];
  let index = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    client.user.setStatus("online");
    client.user.setGame(status[index]);
    index++;
    if (status.length === index) clearInterval(interval);
  }, 1000 * 60 * 10);
};
bot();
```

Comment: yes it looks like what i am looking for, but thank you very much.